# Regex X but not Y, or Z, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need a regex which extracts four or three digit identifiers and excludes the potential years 2013 - 2017.

The source data could look like for example:

```
1011 & 1012 - Mcdonalds - 2015 year 
433,434,4356 - Burger king - 2016
```

Therefore the method in which the data was entered could vary. 2013-2017 isn't needed and can be ignored.

The regex I currently have is `'(\d\d\d\d[^2013-2017]|\d\d\d)'`

The years would clearly not occur in the 3 digit identifiers therefore it would only apply to the 4 digit identifiers.

Simply put, the 2013 - 2017 entries still occur. The regex is applied in the line below. It is named variable so I can see it in the variable explorer of Spyder.

```
cif_regex= '(\d\d\d\d[^2013-2017]|\d\d\d)'
variable = frame["Filename"].str.extractall(cif_regex)
```

I have been playing around with different regexes but clearly don't understand it enough to express it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead and anchor the matches with a word boundary (at least):

```
\b((?!201[3-7])\d{4}|\d{3})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0a5R5/2)

In case the matches are also expected within word chars other than digits (say, within `_` or letters), use negative `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` lookarounds instead of word boundaries:

```
(?<!\d)((?!201[3-7])\d{4}|\d{3})(?!\d)
^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0a5R5/3)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current position (or `\b` - a leading word boundary)
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `(?!201[3-7])\d{4}` - any 4 digits other than `2013`, `2014`, `2015`, `2016` and `2017`
  - `|`
  - `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `)` - Group 1 end
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current position (or `\b` - a trailing word boundary)

In Python (**pay attention to the `r''` prefix** that is required to parse `\b` as a word boundary and not as a backspace char):

```
cif_regex= r'\b((?!201[3-7])\d{4}|\d{3})\b'
variable = frame["Filename"].str.extractall(cif_regex)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry just checked it out now. Yes it works and the explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question if you don't mind - how would you put the extracted matches in a new column of the original data? As the result would be a multindex. Would you unstack and join iit to the original table or can you do this in the line of "frame["Filename"].str.extractall(cif_regex)"?

Comment: @Iwan I am not sure how you want to organize the data and I am not a pandas expert. Try adding after `extractall` something like 1) `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` or 2) `.unstack().apply(','.join, 1)`, or even 3) `.unstack().apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)`, or 4) `.unstack().fillna('')`

Comment: @Iwan It seems `extractall` does not accept any other arguments other than a regex pattern and flags. So, you need to use `unstack` / `apply` / `fillna`, etc.

Comment: Seems to get duplicated index problems. Couldn't you create a numbered index with .set_index(range(len(df))) to avoid the duplicated index created from the extracted digits? I would essentially want to extract the identifiers from the original Filename column and set the new digits as the index, along with the original rows per identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions in regex, but I think a far simpler solution would be to match all 3 and 4 digit numbers first, then filter based on your year range.

```
>>> t = "1011 & 1012 - Mcdonalds - 2015 year \n433,434,4356 - Burger king - 2016"
>>> [m for m in re.findall(r'\d{3,4}', t) if int(m) not in range(2013, 2018)]
['1011', '1012', '433', '434', '4356']
```